# When two libraries have variable types with the same name, how to define the variable type correctly?

Tags: c++

I need to use the armadillo library and opencv library, but I find that both have mat type variables. How can I use them correctly when I use them?

Comment: @Peter Thankyoutoomuch！

Comment: @Peter that should be posted as an answer

Comment: @RemyLebeau - Fair enough.   I wrote that comment fairly quickly (and relying on my potentially-flawed memory relative to the namespaces used by opencv and armadillo).   I'll do a few checks shortly, with a view to turning into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

opencv places type definitions in a namespace named `cv`, and armadillo places type definitions in namespace `arma`.    The reason that libraries use namespaces is to provide a means of avoiding name clashes that results from two libraries using the same name.

The simple approach is then to avoid ANY using directives (e.g. `using namespace cv`, `using namespace arma`, or `using namespace std`) in your code, and use fully qualified names (e.g. `cv::mat` or `arma::mat`, in this case).

The reason to avoid using directives is that the end result can be ambiguity.  For example, when the unqualified name `mat` is used in code following a `using namespace arma` and `using namespace cv`, *both* `cv::mat` and `arma::mat` can be equally viable matches.    Such ambiguity is a diagnosable error.

If you have a name `mat` in the global (unnamed) namespace it is also often preferable to  refer to it explicitly as `::mat`.    Even if using the unqualified name (i.e. `mat`) is acceptable, using the fully qualified name reduces effort for developers (including yourself in future) from having to work out what `mat` actually resolves to.